# Non-threaded alternative to waiting on a condition. (Edit: Proactor pattern with boost.asio?)

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns, boost, boost-asio

I am implementing a message passing algorithm.  Messages pass between adjacent nodes when they have enough information at the node to compose the message - information that is passed to the node from neighbouring nodes.  The implementation is trivial if I make each of messages a thread and use boost::condition to put the thread to sleep until the required information is available.

Unfortunately - I have 100k nodes in the graph which would mean 300k threads.  When I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751737/boostthread-resource-error-when-more-than-32705-threads) how to make that many threads the answer was that I shouldn't - and re-design instead.

**My question is: is there a standard design pattern for waiting for a condition?**
Perhaps some asynchronous control pattern?

**EDIT:** I think I can do this with the proacator pattern.
I have edited to tags to include boost::asio - to see if anyone has suggestions with this.

So the discussion can be concrete, here is how the messages are defined so far:

```
class
Message
{
public:      
  Message(const Node* from, Node* to)
    : m_from(from), m_to(to)
  {}
  void
  operator()()
  {
    m_to->ReceiveMessage( m_from->ComposeMessage() );
  }
private:
  Node *m_from, *m_to;
};
```

These message functors are currently launched with boost::thread.  Then we have

```
class Node
{
    Node(Node* Neighbour1, Node* Neighbour2, Node* Neighbour3); 
   // The messages (currently threads) are created on construction, 
   // The condition locks then sort out when they actually get passed 
   // without me having to think too hard.

    void ReceiveMessage(const Message&); 
    //set m_message from received messages;
    //EDIT This looks like an async write - use boost asio here?

    Message 
    ComposeMessage()
    {
      // If possible I want to implement this function without threads
      // It works great but it if every message is a thread 
      // then I have 300k threads.
      // EDIT: this looks like an async read (use boost asio here?)

      boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
       while (!m_message) //lock the thread until parameter is set.
        m_cond.wait(lock);
      return *m_message;
   }
  private:
    boost::optional<Message> m_message;
    boost::mutex m_mutex;
    boost::condition m_cond;
}
```

I like the transparency of the code and if possible would like to keep the same interfaces by having some alternative to the conditional lock?

Comment: Sounds like you're more or less reinventing CSP. How about finding a CSP library that does all this for you?

Comment: @Jaif - I think you are right.  I hadn't heard of CSP (I knew not doing Computer Science would get me in the end).  It seems I have some googling to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is the [reactor pattern](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/reactor-siemens.pdf). This is where most of the activities do not take too much time and they are doing co-operative multitasking. See [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) for a JavaScript implementation of the idea, but in C++ the [ACE library](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) provides this concept out-of-the-box allowing multiple threads based on the number of cores in the system.

These libraries all depend on some OS APIs that support non-blocking IO on disks, network, etc. When you are not waiting for the OS, but another message source in your app, they provide you with the tools for that.

Comment: thank you, a very interesting article and the Ace library looks like it might do the trick.