# How manny threads can be created in one process?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, operating-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maximum number of threads per process in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux)

just with some curiosity i am asking

```
How manny threads can be created in one process?
```

is there any limitation for that ?

```
How manny process can be created on one system ?
```

is there any limitation for that ?

**I think this would be  differ as per different OS. I am more concern for knowing this value for linux ...**

Comment: Already asked, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

you can increase this by:

```
echo 100000 > /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

use search function :) :
[Maximum number of threads per process in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux)

Comment: This gives you total threads not per process threads limit ;)

Comment: http://dustycodes.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/increasing-number-of-threads-per-process/