# Java `OutOfMemoryError` when creating < 100 threads

Tags: jvm, threadpool, out-of-memory, java

I've been reading and testing and banging my head on the wall for over a day because of this error.

I have some Java code in a class called `Listener` that looks like this

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREADS);
boolean listening = true;
int count = 0;
while (listening) {
    Runnable worker;
    try {
        worker = new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept()); // this is line 254
        executor.execute(worker);
        count++;
        logger.info("{} threads started", count);
    } catch (Exception e1){
        //...
    }
}
```

I have been tweaking the JVM settings `-Xmx` (anywhere from 1 to 15G) and `-Xss` (anywhere from 104k to 512M). The server has 24 GB of RAM, but must also run the database that supports the program.

After 2-20 threads are created (a few dozen exist elsewhere in the program as well), I get the error

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:657)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:943)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1325)
at xxx.Listener.run(Listener.java:254)
```

`$java -version` yields:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (fedora-65.1.11.1.fc16-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

There is always a large amount of free memory on the system when this happens, and other programs continue to execute fine. What is causing Java to think it has no more memory for new threads?

**UPDATE:**
Perhaps this is bigger than I thought- I managed to get this error (only one time) when I used `^C`:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError occurred dispatching signal SIGINT to handler- the VM may need to be forcibly terminated
```

and the same happened when I tried to kill the client (also written in Java and running on the same server, it is a single thread that reads a file and sends it to the server over the socket), so there is definitely a limit beyond the JVM causing one to interfere with the other, but I can't imagine what if I still have free memory and am not using swap at all? Server -Xmx1G -Xss104k Client -Xmx10M

**UPDATE2:**
Abandoning the perl `Forks::Super` library and running the clients from bash let me get up to 34 threads before the server crashed with OOME, so running multiple clients definitely had an impact on the server, but at the same time I should still be able to run more than 34 (68 if one counts the clients) java threads at a time. Which system resources are blocking the creation of more threads (i.e. where should I look to find the hog)? When everything (clients, server, GC...) runs out of memory at the same time, `top` says this about my CPU and memory usage:

```
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  24681040k total,  1029420k used, 23651620k free,    30648k buffers
Swap: 26836988k total,        0k used, 26836988k free,   453620k cached
```

**UPDATE3:** Does the hs_error log below indicate that my java is not 64 bit?

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Cannot create GC thread. Out of system resources.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b24
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.11.1
# Distribution: Fedora release 16 (Verne), package fedora-65.1.11.1.fc16-x86_64
```

Comment: Is ServerThread instance of java.lang.Thread? then it should be started with Thread.start(), and thread pool is of no use. If not, then how are you going to serve socket connection with a simple Runnable? It's  tricky, as tasks under control of a threadpool are not allowed to wait for input, or thread starvation (kind of deadlock) can occur.

Comment: ServerThread is a poorly named class of my own making `public class ServerThread implements Runnable { ... public void run(){ ... } ... }`

 I see your concern that it might be bad to wait for input in a pool (there is a timeout function), but I don't want to create a new thread each time a client connects- that would be huge overhead for relatively short interactions and still wouldn't solve my thread creation problems.

Comment: Have you tested to see how many Threads you can create in a simpler application?

Comment: Perhaps not the best solution, but I have commented out literally the whole program except the part of Listener that starts threads and the part of Server Thread that accepts them (its run function is this: `public void run() { Thread.sleep(30000) }` and I can still only create around 6-11 threads before it runs out of memory.

Comment: What gives you `ulimit -u`? It'll give you the max user processes. maybe you are limited by that.

Comment: `ulimit -u` returns 1024 - that might actually be the problem. How do I change this setting?

Comment: Try this : in `/etc/security/limits.conf` set `user soft nproc [your_val]` and 
`user hard nproc [your_val]`. You may have to add some other config if it's not enough see this link http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Performance_Tuning

Comment: @user121638 You didn't give me any feedback it didn't work?

Comment: I will respond with info when I am able to test it- but I am unfortunately distracted during this holiday weekend.

Comment: For people reading this in the future, please note this bug report in fedora and centos which explains the limitations of editing `/etc/security/limits.conf` [link](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=823030)  @alain.janinm : this solution to change nproc values did solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can be limit by `max user processes`, to know your limit use :

```
ulimit -u
```

To change the limit :

In `/etc/security/limits.conf` set :

```
user soft nproc [your_val] 
user hard nproc [your_val]
```

You may have to add some other config if it's not enough see this [link](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Performance_Tuning).

Note : The OP found this [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=823030) in fedora and centos which explains the limitations of editing `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

Comment: I'd be damed if that * is cause of my headache with version of Centos 6 I am using. wildcard(*) punished in wild. Not just me but pro support guys apparently didn't know about that

Comment: I had to change /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf , this is a security file that also can limit the thread number

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is probably related with JVM being unable to allocate stack memory for new threads. Ironically, this problem can be solved by decreasing heap space (-Xmx) and stack space (-Xss). Check here, for instance, for a good explanation: http://www.blogsoncloud.com/jsp/techSols/java-lang-OutOfMemoryError-unable-to-create-new-native-thread.jsp

Comment: I wish it were so simple, but somehow with `-Xmx1G -Xss104k`I was able to create 6 threads (for a total of less than 40 explicitly created in my program). 104k is the minimum -Xss value on my system, and 1G is nowhere near as large as it needs to be in production. Meanwhile there is still a huge amount (over 8G) free on the system when it runs out of memory.

Comment: 104k is a strange value :) this doc tell about 64k minimum http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#threads_oom

Comment: Strange indeed, but when I start the JVM with less than 104 it throws this message and crashes: `The stack size specified is too small, Specify at least 104k
Could not create the Java virtual machine.`

Answer (score 3):

It's not missing memory for your new threads, it's missing actual threads.
The system is probably stopping you: there's a limit to the number of thread a user can create. You can query it that way:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

Note that you might be impacted by other processes on the same machine, you they create many thread too.
You might find this question useful:
[Maximum number of threads per process in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux)

Comment: `$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` returns 385345- on a server running my program, a few ssh/bash shells, and MySQL, I don't think I'm hitting that limit. Also, some particularly terrible jvm settings cause it to die after fewer threads have been created than others, which suggests that it is a JVM issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification:

You provide a `ServerSocket` to the `Thread`. Do you send Data to that Socket? Maybe you store to much data within the Thread-Context. Tak a look for a pattern, where you store Streamdata in an `byte[]`.

Comment: No, I provide a `Socket` to the thread, `ServerSocket.accept()` returns a `Socket` object. And yes, I pass data to it from another program and read that data, process it, and then disconnect. In the test version, the thread just accepts the socket, waits, then closes it and dies. The socket gets read like a stream, so I don't think that I'm passing the entire contents of that stream to the thread. Moreover, until the client authenticates, it does not send data, to the stream buffer will be only a few hundred bytes.