# Domain Name Does Not Pointing To Installed Java WebApplication In parallel plesk, Remove Port Number

Tags: java, dns, tomcat6, plesk

I have installed One Java Web Application via Plesk 11.0.4 on my server. Now I want My domain name to point my web Application. My address 'www.domain.com' shows blank page. As I installed my Application via plesk , I can Access it on 'www.domain.com:9080/webapp' address. But I want to access my web application from my domain name Like www.domain.com will access my application. My webapp application's root path is :  '/usr/share/tomcat6/work/Catalina/PSA/webapp'

Comment: You need to redirect `http://www.domain.com` to `www.domain.com:9080/webapp` or start you server on port 80 and using webapp as root.  How you do this depends on your web admin tool.

Comment: Hi, I redirected it in index.jsp of ROOT directory of tomcat.But all my other domain names and IP address redirect it to only one application and that shows my port name in browser. Which I dont Want. I want to point my domain to my java webapplication.

Comment: Hi!
I need to configure tomcat on Linux dedicate server only for Java project through Plesk . Following services is running on it. "
1.Apache on port 80
2.Tomcat on port 8080/9080
3.Mysql on port 3306 

Now problem is this, i need to run only java project on this server from port 80.

Thanks

Comment: You need to setup apache as a proxy for tomcat. The last time I did this was almost tens ago so I didn't remember all the details but I am sure there is more documentation on his now. ;)

Comment: Solved ...See My Post On This Forum  [link] (http://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=10485.0) [/link]

Comment: @AJITRANA I saw your post on linxforums... and you saved my tons of time.. Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

This goes for Plesk 11.x: On the page where you can choose the web app, the 'install' button actually has a pulldown menu to its right. There you can choose 'custom install' and install into document root.

[image]