# Rails Migration: PG::ConnectionBad: could not fork new process for connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I'm getting the below error when trying to run migrations locally. But it only happens sometimes, so I'm trying to understand what might cause it.

**Full error:**

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not fork new process for connection: Resource temporarily unavailable
could not fork new process for connection: Resource temporarily unavailable
E, [2017-04-22T10:09:26.381554 #17026] ERROR -- : fsevent: running worker failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Otherwise, the rails console, and accessing the db directly through a client works fine.

I was pointed to another thread which recommended checking,

`ulimit -Hn`

> unlimited

So my descriptor limit doesn't appear to be the issue.

Source: [fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079087/fork-retry-resource-temporarily-unavailable)

**Update:**

It consistently fails when the rails server (Puma) is running, but works when its not.

Comment: Can you post the memory conception, while rails app is running and when it is not? Fork takes up memory as its creating a new process. It could be possible that your code is failing because it doesn't have enough RAM.