# UNIX: Maximum number of threads in a program

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, posix

My c progam is not able to create more than `8 threads`. It returns the error code `EAGAIN(11)`. Which is for lack of resources available. Before posting this question I googled for its solution but could not get much out of that. Here are the detail I have found for my program and unix system.

My thread creation functions is :-

```
thread_initialise(File *CFG_FILE)
{
        int total_pthreads; //reads number of threads I want for the program from configuration file.
        int rc =0 ;
        for (i = 0; i < total_pthreads; i++) 
        {
            rc = pthread_create (&pthread_list[i], NULL, (fp)(begin_worker_pthread), NULL);
            if (rc !=0) printf("Thread creation Error Code: %d",rc);
        }
}
```

Memory consumed by my program while execution is: `pmap -x <pid> = 1111844`

Unix Version:`uname -a = Linux 2.6.18-308.24.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Nov 21 11:42:14 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Thread Max value in unix `cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max = 81920`

`ulimit -u max user processes              (-u) 16000`

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 40960
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 3000000
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 5857280
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 512000
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 16000
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Please help how the maximum number of threads is calculated/ fixed by my system. I want to increase my threads to `32`.

Comment: What about virtual memory uses? and stack size? ulimit -a will show it.

Comment: How much RAM is the machine equipped with?

Comment: @rakib I have added the values of `ulimit -a `

Comment: @CodeCodeCode have you tried increasing ulimit -u 32000 ? ie max user processes?

Comment: 512 MB stacks?  Why?  How?

Comment: @MartinJames Is it too high? I dont know how much is required for my process? Is there any way we can find out that minimum Stack size for my executable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `ulimit -s 4000` from terminal. Now you can run more thread than before, but you will meet segmentation fault in some stage.

number of threads = total virtual memory / (stack size*1024*1024)

> The number of threads per process can be increased by increasing total
>   virtual memory or by decreasing stack size. But, decreasing stack size
>   too much can lead to code failure due to stack overflow while max
>   virtual memory is equals to the swap memory.

further information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux) post clearly explained.

Comment: It helped me by setting `ulimit -s 4000`. but I am not sure about how much minimum stack size can be there for my program. I am afraid if it may lead to program failure at some point after execution. Virtual memory is  already `ulimit -v unlimited`

Comment: max virtual memory is equals to the swap memory. setup swap memeory for your os this may help. I'm not sure about this.

Comment: send the result of swapon -s

Comment: its says cmd not found: `swapon -s
-bash: swapon: command not found`

Comment: @CodeCodeCode which operating system you are using?

Comment: `number of threads = total virtual memory / (stack size*1024*1024)`  My virtual memory is unlimted, so acc to your formula, the number of threds should be unlimted, atleast more than 8.

Comment: @CodeCodeCode try this. cat /proc/swaps it will work under ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

After all above R&D I have found for my systems is that `Maximum number of threads for program = Memory Size(RAM) / Stack Size`. This calculation has worked for my system.

Though I have my Virtual Memory set as unlimited, I can not increase my number of threads than the above calculation.

In a sparate question I have asked for Minimum Stack Size for a program, so that the program never gets failed. Here is the link : [UNIX: What should be Stack Size (ulimit -s) in UNIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483883/unix-what-should-be-stack-size-ulimit-s-in-unix/18486885#18486885)