# Whether Thread or Process in C utilizes more CPU ?? Which one is better for multi processing?

Tags: c, linux

I tried using Multiple threads. I can't go beyond a thread limit. Is there any other way to achieve simultaneous processing.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux

Comment: It depends,. What is your use case? Do you need tight coupling? Shared memory?

Comment: If you're hitting the thread limit, you're almost always doing something wrong. You need to explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Each process has it's own virtual address space, so a context switch between processes requires more CPU overhead to switch the virtual address space than a context switch between threads, which all share the same virtual address space.

Comment: Thanks. Say if i want to use 1000 tcp connections and need simultaneous read/write in 1000 tcp sockets. For this scenario, i need to use 1000 threads for reading/writing in 1000 sockets simultaneously. Am i right ? or What is the efficient way to achieve good performance without loss/delay in read/write ??