# Creating a huge amount of objects(neuron) and connecting randomly using dictionaries

Tags: python, multithreading, neural-network, julia, perceptron

I'm experimentally trying to create a new kind of neural network with these criterias:

- Each neuron must be a separate object.
- Each neuron should have its own thread.
- Network must be connected partially and randomly (at startup).
- Neurons have to run asynchronously for calculating its output, updating its weights etc.

These are my implementation attempts in Julia and Python:

**Python**

```
import random
import itertools
import time
import signal
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing

POTENTIAL_RANGE = 110000 # Resting potential: -70 mV Membrane potential range: +40 mV to -70 mV --- Difference: 110 mV = 110000 microVolt --- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membrane_potential
ACTION_POTENTIAL = 15000 # Resting potential: -70 mV Action potential: -55 mV --- Difference: 15mV = 15000 microVolt --- https://faculty.washington.edu/chudler/ap.html
AVERAGE_SYNAPSES_PER_NEURON = 8200 # The average number of synapses per neuron: 8,200 --- http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2778101

# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuron

class Neuron():

    neurons = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.connections = {}
        self.potential = 0.0
        self.error = 0.0
        #self.create_connections()
        #self.create_axon_terminals()
        Neuron.neurons.append(self)
        self.thread = Thread(target = self.activate)
        #self.thread.start()
        #self.process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.activate)

    def fully_connect(self):
        for neuron in Neuron.neurons[len(self.connections):]:
            if id(neuron) != id(self):
                self.connections[id(neuron)] = round(random.uniform(0.1, 1.0), 2)

    def partially_connect(self):
        if len(self.connections) == 0:
            neuron_count = len(Neuron.neurons)
            for neuron in Neuron.neurons[len(self.connections):]:
                if id(neuron) != id(self):
                    if random.randint(1,neuron_count/100) == 1:
                        self.connections[id(neuron)] = round(random.uniform(0.1, 1.0), 2)
            print "Neuron ID: " + str(id(self))
            print "    Potential: " + str(self.potential)
            print "    Error: " + str(self.error)
            print "    Connections: " + str(len(self.connections))

    def activate(self):
        while True:
            '''
            for dendritic_spine in self.connections:
                if dendritic_spine.axon_terminal is not None:
                    dendritic_spine.potential = dendritic_spine.axon_terminal.potential
                    print dendritic_spine.potential
                self.neuron_potential += dendritic_spine.potential * dendritic_spine.excitement
            terminal_potential = self.neuron_potential / len(self.axon_terminals)
            for axon_terminal in self.axon_terminals:
                axon_terminal.potential = terminal_potential
            '''
            #if len(self.connections) == 0:
            #   self.partially_connect()
            #else:
            self.partially_connect()
            pass

            '''
            if abs(len(Neuron.neurons) - len(self.connections) + 1) > 0:
                self.create_connections()

            if abs(len(Neuron.neurons) - len(self.axon_terminals) + 1) > 0:
                self.create_axon_terminals()
            '''

class Supercluster():

    def __init__(self,size):
        for i in range(size):
            Neuron()
        print str(size) + " neurons created."
        self.n = 0
        self.build_connections()
        #pool = Pool(4, self.init_worker)
        #pool.apply_async(self.build_connections(), arguments)
        #map(lambda x: x.partially_connect(),Neuron.neurons)
        #map(lambda x: x.create_connections(),Neuron.neurons)
        #map(lambda x: x.create_axon_terminals(),Neuron.neurons)

    def build_connections(self):
        for neuron in Neuron.neurons:
            self.n += 1
            #neuron.thread.start()
            neuron.partially_connect()
            print "Counter: " + str(self.n)

Supercluster(10000)
```

**Julia**

```
global neurons = []

type Neuron
    connections::Dict{UInt64,Float16}
    potential::Float16
    error::Float16

    function Neuron(arg1,arg2,arg3)
        self = new(arg1,arg2,arg3)
        push!(neurons, self)
    end

end

function fully_connect(self)
    for neuron in neurons
        if object_id(neuron) != object_id(self)
            self.connections[object_id(neuron)] = rand(1:100)/100
            #push!(self.connections, rand(1:100)/100)
        end
    end
end

function partially_connect(self)
    if isempty(self.connections)
        neuron_count = length(neurons)
        for neuron in neurons
            if object_id(neuron) != object_id(self)
                if rand(1:neuron_count/100) == 1
                    self.connections[object_id(neuron)] = rand(1:100)/100
                    #push!(self.connections, rand(1:100)/100)
                end
            end
        end
        println("Neuron ID: ",object_id(self))
        println("    Potential: ",self.potential)
        println("    Error: ",self.error)
        println("    Connections: ",length(self.connections))
    end
end

function Build()
    for i = 1:10000
        Neuron(Dict(),0.0,0.0)
    end
    println(length(neurons), " neurons created.")
    n = 0
    @parallel for neuron in neurons
        n += 1
        partially_connect(neuron)
        println("Counter: ",n)
    end
end

Build()
```

**Firstly**, **these parts** that are making connections between each neuron partially and randomly, **taking too much time**. *How can I speed up this process/part?*

**Python**

```
def build_connections(self):
    for neuron in Neuron.neurons:
        self.n += 1
        #neuron.thread.start()
        neuron.partially_connect()
        print "Counter: " + str(self.n)
```

**Julia**

```
n = 0
@parallel for neuron in neurons
    n += 1
    partially_connect(neuron)
    println("Counter: ",n)
```

**Secondly, is that a good idea to give each neuron, its own thread** *when my goal is creating at least a million neuron?* It means it will be like a million thread.

What I'm trying to do here is **imitating the biological neural networks** in the strict sense, **instead of using matrix calculations**.

**ADDITION:**

New version of `partially_connect` function according to answer:

```
def partially_connect(self):
    if len(self.connections) == 0:
        neuron_count = len(Neuron.neurons)
        #for neuron in Neuron.neurons:
        elected = random.sample(Neuron.neurons,100)
        for neuron in elected:
            if id(neuron) != id(self):
                #if random.randint(1,neuron_count/100) == 1:
                self.connections[id(neuron)] = round(random.uniform(0.1, 1.0), 2)
        print "Neuron ID: " + str(id(self))
        print "    Potential: " + str(self.potential)
        print "    Error: " + str(self.error)
        print "    Connections: " + str(len(self.connections))
```

Performance dramatically increased.

Comment: I can't answer your question, unfortunately, but just a suggestion - maybe use less bold and italics? It is a bit hard to read. Best of luck :)

Comment: yeah you can't do a million threads. why would you even want to do this? Python can't into multithreading for performance gain because of the global interpreter lock.

Comment: @DonkeyKong Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: @SebastianWozny I know because of the GIL issue, I'm also trying to write the same algorithm in Julia Language.

Comment: @SebastianWozny besides the GIL issue of Python. On Operating System level, Is creating a million thread, possible or sensible?

Comment: this thread says no http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux

Comment: Can you explain, in written prose, what you want/expect the behavior of the `partially_connect()` method to be?

Comment: @AustinHastings It's picking 100 neurons on average and appending their object id as key and a randomly picked weight as value to connections(a dictionary) attribute of the neuron.

Comment: this might be a good candidate for micro-threads aka **coroutines**, using either tornado or asyncio. Each neurons could communicate with the supercluster via some sockets (even via websockets), their could each run their sub-coroutines, periodic callbacks etc...

Comment: @Apero Oh, thanks for the information I'm not an expert and I wasn't know much about coroutines. Do you have any idea for my first question, speeding up the creation/startup?

Comment: again, coroutines could make most of your code non-blocking, which means that you could "defer" the build_connections to the io_loop, which would do it asynchronously, and make your for loop really fast. Async programming takes a lot of time to understand but is really powerful. Good luck.

Comment: @Apero I understood. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ben Darnel is the guy who maintains tornado and could really help on this. I am not sure I can tag him here though. http://stackoverflow.com/users/2805033/ben-darnell

Comment: this can help understanding asyncio for your needs: http://www.pythonsandbarracudas.com/blog/2015/11/22/developing-a-computational-pipeline-using-the-asyncio-module-in-python-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at this code:

```
def partially_connect(self):
    if len(self.connections) == 0:
        neuron_count = len(Neuron.neurons)
        for neuron in Neuron.neurons[len(self.connections):]:
            if id(neuron) != id(self):
                if random.randint(1,neuron_count/100) == 1:
                    self.connections[id(neuron)] = round(random.uniform(0.1, 1.0), 2)
```

And based on your reply to my comment on the OP, here's a couple of things:

1. You are making a copy of the lists when you use syntax like `L[0:]`. The slice syntax is making a shallow copy of the `Neuron.neurons` array for each call to your function. That's an **O(n)** operation, and since you call `partially_connect` once for each neuron in your `build_connections` function, that makes it **O(n²)**. (Yikes!)
2. You are doing work in Python that can and should be done in the library (in C, we hope!). Have a look at e.g. the `random.paretovariate()` and `random.sample()` functions. You could easily compute `num_connections = random.paretovariate(1.0) * 100` and then say `connected_nodes = random.sample(neurons, num_connections)`. Filter out `self` from the `connected_nodes` and you're done.

I think you can get a big performance boost by eliminating n² behavior and by using the built-in library routines.

**ADDITION**

Responding to your addition, consider this:

```
def partially_connect(self):
    if len(self.connections) == 0:
        elected = random.sample(Neuron.neurons,100)
        try:
            elected.remove(self)
        except ValueError:
            pass

        for neuron in elected:
            self.connections[id(neuron)] = round(random.uniform(0.1, 1.0), 2)
```

(I'm ignoring the prints for now.)

I don't know how you would communicate from a neuron to its connected neurons, without iterating all the neurons looking for a match of `id()` values. I'd suggest you store a reference to the connect objects as the key, and use the weight as the value:

```
self.connections = [n:round(random.uniform(0.1, 1.0), 2) for n in elected]
```

This assumes you need to traverse the links from source to target, of course.

As for threading solutions, I don't have a good suggestion. A little googling leads me to some old email threads (heh!) that mention numbers like 405 and 254 as being thread creation limits. I haven't seen any documents saying "Python threading is now UNLIMITED!" or whatever, so I suspect you're going to have to alter the way you implement your solution.

Comment: `[len(self.connections):]` was coming from my old revisions and I forgot to remove. I removed now but still there is no difference on behalf of performance. How can I get rid of **O(n²)** and make it **O(n)** complexity? Still, I couldn't understand.

Comment: Your second statement, using `random.sample()` dramatically increased the performance. Thanks a lot! But I still couldn't understand your first statement.

Comment: On the first part, you can't make it down, but you could make it go away. Just converting from `neurons[len(self.connections):]` to `neurons` will eliminate the needless copy.

Comment: I made an addition to question, please take a look. Is it covering all of your statements? Lastly, do you have any idea for threading issue? There will be like a million thread. In comments @Apero suggested using **tornado** or **asyncio**. Do you have any addition to this suggestion?

Comment: See my addition above. ;-) I don't know about tornado or asyncio, so you'll have to investigate those on your own.

Answer (score 2):

In Julia, if performance matters: don't use globals (see your `neurons` array) and don't use untyped arrays (again, see your `neurons` array). See the [performance tips](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/). You should also profile to determine where your bottlenecks are. I'd strongly recommend trying it without the `@parallel`, until you can get it fast.

I took at look at it myself, and in addition to these I found some surprising bottlenecks:

- `rand(1:neuron_count/100)` creates a floating-point range, not an integer range. This was a huge bottleneck, which profiling instantly identified. Use `rand(1:neuron_count÷100)`.
- better not to call `object_id`, just use `!(neuron === self)`. Or maybe even better, pass the `neurons` as an array and the integer index of the entry to want to modify.

Fixing these items, I managed to get the execution time of your program (after getting rid of the `@parallel`, which is unlikely to be helpful, and commenting out the text-display) down from about 140 seconds to 4 seconds. Almost all the runtime is simply spent generating random numbers; you might be able to accelerate this by generating a large pool all at once, rather than generating them one-by-one.

This uses the ProgressMeter package (which you have to install) to display progress.

```
using ProgressMeter

type Neuron
    connections::Dict{UInt64,Float16}
    potential::Float16
    error::Float16
end

function fully_connect(self, neurons)
    for neuron in neurons
        if object_id(neuron) != object_id(self)
            self.connections[object_id(neuron)] = rand(1:100)/100
            #push!(self.connections, rand(1:100)/100)
        end
    end
end

function partially_connect(self, neurons)
    if isempty(self.connections)
        neuron_count = length(neurons)
        for neuron in neurons
            if !(neuron === self)
                if rand(1:neuron_count÷100) == 1
                    self.connections[object_id(neuron)] = rand(1:100)/100
                    #push!(self.connections, rand(1:100)/100)
                end
            end
        end
#         println("Neuron ID: ",object_id(self))
#         println("    Potential: ",self.potential)
#         println("    Error: ",self.error)
#         println("    Connections: ",length(self.connections))
    end
end

function Build()
    neurons = [Neuron(Dict(),0.0,0.0) for i = 1:10000]
    println(length(neurons), " neurons created.")
    @showprogress 1 "Connecting neurons..." for neuron in neurons
        partially_connect(neuron, neurons)
    end
    neurons
end

neurons = Build()
```