# Thread kills process because of Sleep function

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, c++11

```
thread_local int sum = 0;   
void thrCal(int row, int column, int n, int &result, const vector<vector<int>> &A, const vector<vector<int>> &B)
{
    Sleep(1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += A[row][i] * B[i][column];
    result = sum;
} //calculates each element with thread

void calculate(vector<vector<int>> &A, const vector<vector<int>> &B)
{
    vector<vector<int>> temp;
    vector<thread> T;
    int row = A.size(), column = B[0].size(), n = A[0].size();

    cout << "check print" << endl;

    temp.resize(row);
    for(auto &i : temp)
        i.resize(column);

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
            T.push_back(thread(thrCal, i, j, n, ref(temp[i][j]), ref(A), ref(B)));

    for (auto &i : T)
        i.join();

    A = move(temp);
} //matrix A = A * B with multithread

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> *A = new vector<vector<int>>[3];
    vector<vector<int>> result;

    A[0].resize(50);
    A[1].resize(50);
    A[2].resize(50);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (auto &j : A[i])
            j.resize(50);

    result = A[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        calculate(result, A[i]);

}
```

If `Sleep(1000)` call is *not* present, this code works as expected.

If `Sleep(1000)` call is present, the `calculate()` function works first time, but second time, it terminates process when the loop around `T.push_back` ends.

Why this situation happens?

(Windows7 and microsoft visual studio 2015)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please be more precise about what threads run and when, and on what conditions they terminate and how.

Comment: also explain what "sum" is, because you appear to have concurrent access to this variable.

Comment: Cannot reproduce [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8af64aa66d694172).

Comment: I edit the code. and if size of A = [5 * 5], this code well activates but A = [50 * 50] doesn't activate well.

Comment: I solve this problem because timers are over 1430 in my computer than terminates process.
but i don't know why this happnes.

Comment: Look at [maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux), as `50*50` threads is `2500` threads (whereas without sleep, thread has time to finish).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the code correctly, you're trying to run 2,500 threads simultaneously.

On a 32-bit process with default settings, [the maximum number of threads you can possibly run simultaneously is 2,048.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/07/05/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/)  More than this, and you run out of virtual address space, causing the process to crash.

But even if you messed with the settings or recompiled as 64-bit, this is not a sensible approach; it will perform very poorly.  Instead, use a work queue or some other technique to farm the work out to a smaller number of threads; you will typically get optimum performance if you have one thread for each CPU core.