# How can I get a gstreamer pipeline by name?

Tags: c, gstreamer

If a pipeline is created `GstElement *pipeline = gst_pipeline_new (session_id);` on my server whenever a user visits **http://myurl.com/new?session_id=123&file_path=/vids/vid.mp4** (mp4 videos are streamed to a RTMP server), how can I use the name of the pipeline **"123"** to set the pipeline state to not playing when the user visits **http://myurl.com/to_not_playin?session_id=123**? Each visit to **http://myurl.com/new** launches gstreamer in a new thread (because my webserver is asynchronous and I want multiple users to use the platform) then the different elements/pads are created and linked.

Comment: Do keep in mind that tying a thread to each and every request effectively makes the maximum number of users equal to the number of threads your OS can spawn. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux) for a question concerning Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get a pipeline by name generically in GStreamer, you should store the `name -> pipeline` map yourself if you need it.

Comment: I created a `GHashTable* my_hash_table = g_hash_table_new_full(g_str_hash, g_str_equal, g_free, (GDestroyNotify) g_object_unref);` and add the pipelines after I create them `g_hash_table_insert(my_hash_table, pipeline_name, pipeline)` then retrieve the one I want with `GstElement* pipeline = g_hash_table_lookup(my_hash_table, "pipeline name");`

Answer (score 0):

How to set a name on a GStreamer pipeline:

```
gst_element_set_name(pipeline, "gbxpipeline");
```

How to get the named pipeline in a message handler:

```
if (!strcmp("gbxpipeline", strcmp(GST_MESSAGE_SRC_NAME(msg))) {
    // You've got your pipeline!
}
```

Reference: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstElement.html#gst-element-set-name