# What is the maximum number of threads a Rust program can spawn?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I am seeing conflicting information about the maximum number of threads that a Rust program can spawn; some suggest arbitrary numbers like "32", sometimes a multiple of the number of cores the CPU has.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [threads provided by the Rust standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/) are "OS threads", that is, they use the facilities of your operating system.

Therefore, a Rust program has no limit imposed by Rust itself, but rather, this limit would result from whatever your OS lets you do. You'd have to know the OS to know the true answer, which would be different for a given OS. For example, see this question: ["Maximum number of threads per process in Linux?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux)

Comment: This is a terrible design. How come nobody needs to constraint the environment? Go instead uses `GOMAXPROCS=1` and works wonders. Now rust applications are being killed by the OS upon spawning threads because of thread policies.

Comment: Because Rust is a systems language, there's simply no way to enforce this. Any code any user writes can invoke the OS APIs to spawn new threads directly, even if Rust had some sort of limit around `thread::spawn`, it wouldn't prevent this from happening.