# Where does the limitation of the thread pool come from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Using the following code, I found that the maximum size of the `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` is 11689 (on my machine). If I make it bigger, I get

> RuntimeError: can't start new thread

Can somebody explain where this comes from? 11689 seems like a weird system constant... so maybe I ran out of a resource?

Please note: This is not about how to choose the best number of threads for a Thread pool. This question is about where the 11689 comes from?

### Code

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux? There's probably an OS-level limit, and 11689 is esseintially that number minus all the threads already running in all the other processes on your machine.

Comment: Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 MATE)

Comment: @TomDalton `cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
125150` looks about right. Should I post a community wiki answer?

Comment: (I still wonder why 125150... why not 125000 or 128000?)

Comment: (See https://stackoverflow.com/q/344203/562769 for the command)

Answer (score 0):

A brief look at the CPython source code handling [threads](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/13ff24582c99dfb439b1af7295b401415e7eb05b/Python/thread_pthread.h#L157) suggests the interpreter is not [delving into details](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/13ff24582c99dfb439b1af7295b401415e7eb05b/Python/thread_pthread.h#L204) too much when a thread creation fails. It just raises the [RuntimeError](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/aa0735f597b072c0eb00404c4d7df359ddc26755/Modules/_threadmodule.c#L1066) you see.

According to `pthread_create` manpage, a thread creation can fail with the following error codes and reasons.

> EAGAIN Insufficient resources to create another thread.
>
> EAGAIN A  system-imposed  limit on the number of threads was encountered.  There are a number of limits that may trigger this error: the RLIMIT_NPROC soft resource limit (set via setrlimit(2)), which limits the number of pro‐
>                 cesses and threads for a real user ID, was reached; the kernel's system-wide limit on the number of processes and threads, /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max, was reached  (see  proc(5));  or  the  maximum  number  of  PIDs,
>                 /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max, was reached (see proc(5)).
>
> ...

My blind guess is that you are incurring in the first problem rather than the second. You might be running out of memory to allocate new threads.

A deeper explanation on ways a thread creation can fail can be found at [this link](http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/problem_of_thread_creation.html).

This is a blind guess though. A more verbose error handling from the interpreter would surely help.