# Why can I create more threads than "free memory" / "thread stack size"?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

In Linux the maximum number of threads is defined as `max_threads = mempages / (8 * THREAD_SIZE / PAGE_SIZE);`, and can be retreived by calling `cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max`. This returns around 14,000 for my raspberry Pi 3. However, when I just create threads in a loop with `pthread_create()`,(which are empty), I can create only 250, before I get`ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)`.

Now I looked at the default stack that is allocated to a process or thread, and that is 8192k. So at around 250 threads I would be using 2GB memory. However, in my mind this also does not add up, because calling `free -m` shows I got total of 1GB memory.

*Since I have 1GB of ram, I expected to be able to only create 125 threads at maximum, not 250, and not 14000.*

*Why can I create 250 threads?*

Comment: this could point you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux

Comment: @harandk I read this, and it did not answer the question to my satisfaction

Answer (score 2):

By default, Linux performs memory overcommit.  This means that you can allocate more anonymous, writable memory than there is physical memory.

You can turn off memory overcommit using:

```
# sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=2
```

This will cause some workloads to fail which work perfectly fine in `vm.overcommit_memory=0` mode.  Some details can be found in the [overcommit accounting documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/vm/overcommit-accounting.html).

Comment: This is a very interesting answer! However, this did not change anything. Do I just input the command in console?

Comment: Yes, it's a command that has to run as root. How much swap space do you have? Try disabling swap as well.