# Why number of created thread is less than thread-max?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, gcc9

With this code:

```cpp
void yield_sleep(void)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    static size_t thread_num;

    auto start{high_resolution_clock::now()};
    std::this_thread::yield();
    auto end{high_resolution_clock::now()};

    std::cout << thread_num++
              << "|Waiting for: "
              << duration_cast<microseconds>(end - start).count()
              << " ms."
              << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<std::thread> tp(62434);

    std::generate(tp.begin(), tp.end(), []() { return std::thread(yield_sleep); });
    std::for_each(tp.begin(), tp.end(), [](auto& t) { t.join(); });
}
```

The program create ~32718 thread and throw an exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Resource temporarily unavailable
```

But in `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` the value is 62434. What is the problem ? why my program throw an exception during create threads ?

Comment: Does the `threads-max` value represent a per-process limit, or a system wide limit?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/344292/9248466), `thread-max` value is system wide limit.

Comment: Are you sure the number is 32718 and not 32768 (that is exactly MAX_INT16 + 1)(that is a negative value)?

Comment: If it is a system limit, then you need to subtract out the current amount of threads running, plus some buffer.

Comment: I would also search for another constant limiting process threads specifically.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni, It's not same in every run.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate : [Understanding the difference between pid_max, ulimit -u and thread_max](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136854/understanding-the-difference-between-pid-max-ulimit-u-and-thread-max)

Comment: There are many reasons why the system might stop a "fork bomb."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [@1201ProgramAlarm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5231607/1201programalarm) and [@Francois Andrieux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7359094/fran%c3%a7ois-andrieux) in the comments. The `thread-max` value is a system wide limit and for creating much more threads we need to some modifications in kernel settings:

- [Understanding the difference between pid_max, ulimit -u and thread_max](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136854/understanding-the-difference-between-pid-max-ulimit-u-and-thread-max)
- [Maximum number of threads per process in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/344292/9248466)