# Java OutOfMemoryException on using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm, out-of-memory, processbuilder

I have the following problem: I have an Kotlin host application that start another Java programm with

```
 val process = ProcessBuilder(*split("java -jar second.jar").toTypedArray())
            .directory(File(this.directory))
            .redirectErrorStream(true)
            .start();
```

On machine (PopOs 20.04, 16GB Ram) this works fine, but if I run it on the sever (Debian stretch, 8GB Ram ) the second.jar program throws a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached" exception.

Any ideas how I could fix it?

Comment: take a thread dump and analyse

Comment: The error suggests you've hit one of the OS-level limits related to the [maximum number of threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux) or memory mappings. Check `ulimit -u`, `sysctl kernel.pid_max`, `sysctl kernel.threads-max`, `sysctl vm.max_map_count`.

Comment: Meanwhile I have the problem on the  whole server. But I am a bit helpless, because `ulimit -u` returns 62987 but tp just shows ~200 threads.  sysctl kernel.pid_max = 4194304;    sysctl kernel.threads-max = 3090195;  sysctl vm.max_map_count = 65530